# How to open all ports in Oracle Linux 7?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, oracle, oracle-linux

I'm trying to set up a Outline VPN server on my Oracle Cloud Instance. However I keep getting the error

> You won’t be able to access it externally, despite your server being correctly
> set up, because there's a firewall (in this machine, your router or cloud
> provider) that is preventing incoming connections to ports 37019 and 3029.

I tried individually opening ports using the command

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=37019/tcp --permanent`

However the port numbers keep changing after I open them. So is there a way to open all the TCP and UDP ports at once?

Answer (score 2):

To *"open all the TCP and UDP ports at once"*  is in many cases more less equivalent to either:

- disabling your firewall completely (typically not what you want or need)
- white-listing a source  (which is no problem when that concerns specific ip-addresses or ranges and not from everywhere) for example with:

  ```
  firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-source=192.168.1.0/24
  ```

But note that in many cloud environments, as that error message already indicates, in addition to a host based firewall (the iptables rules you manage with `firewall-cmd`) there will be a firewall / network access list / security policy managed outside of the instance itself. That can also be the reason specific  ingress/egress traffic is blocked.
In Oracle cloud that is for example:
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/securityrules.htm